# Deserialize JSON in C# to a LinkedList of Tuples

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a collection of tickets in my HTML code, from which I'm colleting information with JQuery and successfully posting in JSON to codebehind via AJAX.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
                'arrayTickets':
                               [
                                               {"num":1,"rec":"SWAFAD","temp":"0","id":"f39443aa-1ae1-4d18-82b8-468f14dac507"},

                                              {"num":1,"rec":"admin","temp":"0","id":"20bf1fea-b03e-4a28-922a-9618c8c8a73f"}                                           ] 
}
```

The problem is I can't seem to be able to deserialize it to the type of structure I want:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void cmd_gravar_Click(string arrayTickets)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    LinkedList<Tuple<int, string, string, string>> tickets = json.Deserialize<LinkedList<Tuple<int, string, string, string>>>(arrayTickets);
}
```

I get the error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for type of
>   'System.Tuple`4[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

I would like to keep using this structure as I already created a working method that saves the data to the DB with it. This is being done in webforms.

Edit: using VS2012

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember the .net deserializer has issues with Tuples. I think JSON.net should solve your issue

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Usage:

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinkedList<Tuple<int, string, string, string>>>(arrayTickets);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't install the package because I'm in VS2012 and apparently I need NuGet 2.12+ which is not available.

Comment: Wait, turns out I don't need to install it, I can run the code. Problem is that the variable "result" has the correct number of items but the int values are all 0 and strings all null.